# Use background as button in Android?

Tags: android, button, background

I am making and app for android, and currently on the testing stage. When I use the app, I find that it would be a better experience for the user if he or she would be able to press anywhere on the screen, not just the button? I have text and images on the page, but I want the user to be able to click anywhere. So, I was thinking that the best way to do this would be to make the background a button? currently, I have the background set in Html as follows..

```
    android:background="@drawable/woodbackground"
```

Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can assign an OnClickListener event to the main layout element. Just refer to it with it's id.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add :

```
layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        // Do something
    }
});
```